# ANDROID onBackPressed doesnt work for the activity

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle

I implemented the onBackPressed for my activity where it will check the internet connection but when i click the back button in my tablet, it does nothing. I dont understand what is the cause of it. Can help?

**Below is my code**

```
if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder splash = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        splash.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fail)
                .setTitle("No Internet Connection")
                .setMessage(
                        "Please check your internet connection and try again.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Try again",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                Intent splash = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        SplashActivity.class);
                                startActivity(splash);
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Wifi Setting",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = splash.create();
        alert.show();
    } else {
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(login);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}

public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Intent splash = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            SplashActivity.class);
    startActivity(splash);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to close the application on back pressed or check the internet...

Comment: close the application @KumarVivekMitra

Answer (score 4):

just try this code...

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
```

Comment: some text would help this answer

Answer (score 0):

**-** `finish()` is the proper way to close the Activity.

**-** But still if its doesn't, due to some reason use `System.exit(0)` after `finish()`.. this **will surely work**.... I know its crude...but works...

**///////////////////////////// Edited Part///////////////////////////////////////**

**-** override the method `onKeyDown()` of `Activity`.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) { 

               this.finish(); 

            } 
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: is it the proper way to use system.ext(0)?

Comment: @SarahPhil i have already mentioned in my second point that `System.exit(0)` will be a crude way to do it......... but it had worked fine with me till now................

Answer (score 0):

comment, and check

```
//super.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        yourclassname.this.finish();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
        getParent().finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead. I think it will Work for you.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//super.onBackPressed();
// finish your Activity
ActivityName.this.finish();
return;
}
```